# Rewriting inner product in terms of linear combinations of orthonormal basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

If I have an orthonormal basis $B = \{ \pmb {b_{1}}, \pmb {b_{2}}, \dots, \pmb {b_{n}} \}$ for a finite-dimensional inner product space $V$, then it says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis#Basic_formula) that every $\pmb v \in V$ can be written as $\pmb v = \langle \pmb{b_{1}}, \pmb v \rangle \pmb{b_{1}} + \langle \pmb{b_{2}}, \pmb v \rangle \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + \langle \pmb{b_{n}}, \pmb v \rangle \pmb{b_{n}}$, therefore the corresponding [coordinate vector should be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector#Definition)  $$[\pmb v]_{B} = \bigg(\langle \pmb{b_{1}}, \pmb v \rangle, \langle \pmb{b_{2}}, \pmb v \rangle, \dots, \langle \pmb{b_{2}}, \pmb v \rangle \bigg)$$with each coordinate being $v_{i} = \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb v \rangle$. And so I decided to expand out $\langle \pmb u, \pmb v \rangle$ as:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \pmb u, \pmb v \rangle &= \bigg\langle u_{1} \pmb{b_{1}} + u_{2} \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + u_{n} \pmb{b_{n}}, \ \pmb v \bigg\rangle \\ \\
&= u_{1} \langle \pmb{b_{1}},\pmb{v} \rangle + u_{2} \langle \pmb{b_{2}}, \pmb{v} \rangle + \dots + u_{n} \langle \pmb{b_{n}}, \pmb{v} \rangle \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} u_{i} \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb v \rangle  \\
\end{align}
$$
Here, I am ***really*** tempted to just replace $\langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb v \rangle$ with $v_{i}$, and if I do so I get this:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \pmb u, \pmb v \rangle &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} u_{i} \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb v \rangle \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} u_{i} v_{i} \\
&= [\pmb u]_{B} \cdot [\pmb v]_{B}
\end{align}
$$
And so the ***inner product*** of two vectors in $V$ would be the ***dot product*** of the corresponding coordinate vectors over the basis $B$.

But, if I don't substitute, and instead I keep expanding, I get this:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \pmb u, \pmb v \rangle &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} u_{i} \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb v \rangle \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} u_{i} \bigg\langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \ v_{1} \pmb{b_{1}} + v_{2} \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + v_{n} \pmb{b_{n}} \bigg\rangle \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} u_{i} \bigg( \overline{v_{1}} \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb{b_{1}} \rangle + \overline{v_{2}} \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb{b_{2}} \rangle + \dots + \overline{v_{n}} \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb{b_{n}} \rangle \bigg) \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} u_{i} \bigg( \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \overline{v_{j}} \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb{b_{j}} \rangle \bigg) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \sum_{j = 1}^{n} u_{i} \overline{v_{j}} \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb{b_{j}} \rangle
\end{align}
$$
We know that $\langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb{b_{i}} \rangle = 1$, and if $i \ne j$ then $\langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb{b_{j}} \rangle = 0$. Therefore non-zero terms occur only when $i=j$, so:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \pmb u, \pmb v \rangle &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \sum_{j = 1}^{n} u_{i} \overline{v_{j}} \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb{b_{j}} \rangle = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} u_{i} \overline{v_{i}} \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb{b_{i}} \rangle \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} u_{i} \overline{v_{i}}
\end{align}
$$
And so this way, I get a ***different*** expression for $\langle u, v \rangle$, which could potentially mean:

1. $v_{i} = \overline{v_{i}}$, which implies $\langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb v \rangle = \langle \pmb v, \pmb{b_{i}} \rangle$.
2. The first method is wrong. Perhaps there's a subtlety where you can't "just replace" $\langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb v \rangle$ with $v_{i}$.
3. The second method is wrong. Perhaps I made a mistake somewhere, when expanding.
4. Both methods are wrong.

Is it any of these? Whats going on.

---

**EDIT:** as per [@RyeCatcher](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1078841/ryecatcher)'s comments, my decomposition of $\pmb v$ leads to $\langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb v \rangle = \langle \pmb v, \pmb{b_{i}} \rangle$, which is *just wrong*; the correct formula should include complex conjugation.

From this I am *guessing* that the correct decomposition is, $\pmb v = \overline{\langle \pmb{b_{1}}, \pmb v \rangle} \pmb{b_{1}} + \overline{\langle \pmb{b_{2}}, \pmb v \rangle} \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + \overline{\langle \pmb{b_{n}}, \pmb v \rangle} \pmb{b_{n}} = \langle \pmb v, \pmb{b_{1}} \rangle \pmb{b_{1}} + \langle \pmb v, \pmb{b_{2}} \rangle \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + \langle \pmb v, \pmb{b_{n}} \rangle \pmb{b_{n}}$, and therefore $v_{i} = \langle \pmb v, \pmb{b_{i}} \rangle, \ \overline{v_{i}} = \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb v \rangle$.

Using this, my *first* attempt at expanding becomes:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \pmb u, \pmb v \rangle &= \bigg\langle u_{1} \pmb{b_{1}} + u_{2} \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + u_{n} \pmb{b_{n}}, \ \pmb v \bigg\rangle \\ \\
&= u_{1} \langle \pmb{b_{1}},\pmb{v} \rangle + u_{2} \langle \pmb{b_{2}}, \pmb{v} \rangle + \dots + u_{n} \langle \pmb{b_{n}}, \pmb{v} \rangle \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} u_{i} \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb v \rangle  \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} u_{i} \overline{v_{i}}
\end{align}
$$
So it's the same as my *second* method, and everything is resolved. However, my new questions are:

1. Is the new decomposition correct?
2. If it is, then how does the formula $\pmb v = \sum_{\pmb b \in B} \langle \pmb b,\pmb v \rangle \pmb b$, (found on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis#Basic_formula) wiki page) become $\pmb v = \overline{\langle \pmb{b_{1}}, \pmb v \rangle} \pmb{b_{1}} + \overline{\langle \pmb{b_{2}}, \pmb v \rangle} \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + \overline{\langle \pmb{b_{n}}, \pmb v \rangle} \pmb{b_{n}}$? Is this related to different inner product conventions between Maths/physics?

---

**EDIT 2:** I attempted this from a different direction. Because $B = \{ \pmb {b_{1}}, \pmb {b_{2}}, \dots, \pmb {b_{n}} \}$ is a basis, it means that for every $\pmb v \in V$, there exist some unique scalars $v_{1}, v_{2},\dots,v_{n} \in F$ for which: $$\pmb v = v_{1} \pmb{b_{1}} + v_{2} \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + v_{n} \pmb{b_{n}}$$Therefore, we have that:
$$
\begin{align}
\overline{\langle \pmb{b_{1}}, \pmb v \rangle} \pmb{b_{1}} + \overline{\langle \pmb{b_{2}}, \pmb v \rangle} \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + \overline{\langle \pmb{b_{n}}, \pmb v \rangle} \pmb{b_{n}} &= \langle \pmb v, \pmb{b_{1}} \rangle \pmb{b_{1}} + \langle \pmb v, \pmb{b_{2}} \rangle \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + \langle \pmb v, \pmb{b_{n}} \rangle \pmb{b_{n}} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \langle \pmb v, \pmb{b_{i}} \rangle \pmb{b_{i}} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v_{1} \pmb{b_{1}} + v_{2} \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + v_{n} \pmb{b_{n}}, \pmb{b_{i}} \rangle \pmb{b_{i}} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \bigg( v_{1} \langle \pmb{b_{1}}, \pmb{b_{i}} \rangle \pmb{b_{i}} + v_{2} \langle \pmb{b_{2}}, \pmb{b_{i}} \rangle \pmb{b_{i}} + \dots + v_{n} \langle \pmb{b_{n}}, \pmb{b_{i}} \rangle \pmb{b_{i}} \bigg) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n v_{i} \langle \pmb{b_{i}}, \pmb{b_{i}} \rangle \pmb{b_{i}} = \sum_{i=1}^n v_{i} \pmb{b_{i}} \\
&= v_{1} \pmb{b_{1}} + v_{2} \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + v_{n} \pmb{b_{n}} \\
&= \pmb v \\ \\
\text{Therefore we have: } &
\pmb v = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle \pmb v, \pmb{b_{i}} \rangle \pmb{b_{i}}
\end{align} 
$$
So, as is pointed out by [@Arturo Magidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/742/arturo-magidin) in the comments, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis#Basic_formula) formula is correct for physics convention, but not for maths convention.

Comment: The decomposition of $v$ at the beggining is wrong for this case, it should include complex conjugation. Try to calculate $\langle \mathbf{b_i}, \mathbf{v}\rangle$ using your first equation and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Wikipedia has the wrong formula (or the correct formula for the convention that inner products are linear in the second component, as is common in physics); I've left a note in the talk page. With inner products linear in the first component, the correct formula is that if $B$ is an orthonormal basis, then $\mathbf{x}=\sum_{\mathbf{b}\in B}\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{b}\rangle\mathbf{b}$.

Comment: I've corrected the Wikipedia page. The change was introduced in May 2021, and went apparently unnoticed.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks! Yeah that makes sense, updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @the thinker Great work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $\pmb v = \langle \pmb{b_{1}}, \pmb v \rangle \pmb{b_{1}} + \langle \pmb{b_{2}}, \pmb v \rangle \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + \langle \pmb{b_{n}}, \pmb v \rangle \pmb{b_{n}}$ then you would get
\begin{align*}
\langle \pmb{b_i}, \pmb v\rangle = \langle \pmb{b_i},\langle \pmb{b_{1}}, \pmb v \rangle \pmb{b_{1}}\rangle + \langle \pmb{b_i},\langle \pmb{b_{2}}, \pmb v \rangle \pmb{b_{2}}\rangle \pmb{b_{2}} + \dots + \langle \pmb{b_i},\langle \pmb{b_{n}}, \pmb v \rangle \pmb{b_{n}}\rangle = \langle \pmb{b_i}, \langle \pmb{b_i}, \pmb{v}\rangle \pmb{b_i} \rangle  = \overline{\langle \pmb{b_i},\pmb{v}}\rangle
\end{align*}
which is wrong in general.

Can you guess the correct formula?

Comment: I've attempted guessing the correct formula, updated the question accordingly